# Selenium Python check is list of elements sorted

Tags: python, list, sorting, selenium

in my test i'm getting list of elements, and wanna verify is the list sorted but i'm getting error:

```
>       assert emp == sorted(emp)
E       TypeError: unorderable types: WebElement() < WebElement()
```

Here is my code:

```
def test_sorted_employee_list(driver):
    login(driver, username="Admin", password="Password")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#menu_pim_viewPimModule").click()
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("First (& Middle) Name").click()
    emp = employee_list(driver)
    assert emp == sorted(emp)

   `def employee_list(driver):
    userslist = []
    while True:
        try:
            # goes to first page,second..etc. and gets list of elements
            for i in range(1, 50):
                driver.find_element_by_link_text("%s" % i).click()
                userslist.extend(driver.find_elements_by_xpath\
                                           ("//tbody/tr/td[3]"))
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break
    return userslist`
```

Comment: Sorted by what? How is it suppose to compare a WebElement?

Comment: For a string, you can sort alphabetically. For an integer you can sort numerically. For a webelement what do you sort by?

Comment: so that's is my question, what i have to do, to check is that list is sorted alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this line

```
userslist.extend(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody/tr/td[3]"))
```

with

```
userslist.extend([elem.text for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody/tr/td[3]")])
```

to get the the list of text nodes instead of list of WebElements

Comment: it helped, thanks
but should've add assert `assert emp == sorted(emp, key=str.lower)`

Comment: It depends on how you want to sort your list. If you want `['a', 'b', 'A', 'B']`, then `key=str.lower` should be used. Otherwise (if you want `['A', 'B', 'a', 'b']`) then you might specify no key

Comment: Andersson@ yeah, in my application it sorted by lower keys, so i had to, thank you